# Unable to add a source with url that begins with 'git@github.com'

Tags: ios, github, cocoapods

In my Podfile I have this kind of operations:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'git@github.com:xxxxxxx/cocoapods-specs.git'
```

And recive :

```
 Unable to add a source with url `git@github.com:xxxxxxx/cocoapods-specs.git`
```

But when I change `git@github.com` to `https://github.com` everything is working fine.

Could you pls share you're experience about how could I use `git@github.com` kind of the declaration ?

Should I use some macros ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to use `git@github.com:xxxxxxx/cocoapods-specs.git` style you should add SSH keys to verify you're account.

You can do this in **SSH and GPG** keys section in GitHub settings tab.

To generete SSH key pls follow this [link](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/).